# How to assign an int to unsigned long using C?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am using C language. There is a function named "npu_session_total".
Then, I will use the return value of this func and assign it to an unsigned long variable "accelerated_count".

```
int npu_session_total(void)
{
    // this will return an int
    return atomic_read(&npu_session_count);
}
........
unsigned long accelerated_count = npu_session_total();
```

Will this cause any problems? How can I do the cast?

Thanks!

Comment: can the session count go negative? If yes, then yes it will cause problems. Will the session count ever be more than range of int? if yes, then yes it will cause problems

Comment: Conversion from `int` to `unsigned long` is done implicitly. No need to do anything, as long as you are happy with its behavior (i.e. negative vaues wrapping around `ULONG_MAX`). In other words, whethter it will cause "problems" depends on what you want/expect from it. And you are not saying much.

Comment: The session count should be positive and within range of max_int. So I think it will be fine if I have a small positive int value and I assign it to an unsigned long variable?

Comment: Then you are fine!

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Why `unsigned long accelerated_count`? why not `int accelerated_count` ? What's the benefit here?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning an `int` to a `unsigned long` can be done simply as OP did.  It is well defined in C.  When `some_int_value >= 0` it will always fit unchanged into an `unsigned long`.

```
INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX <= ULONG_MAX
```

No cast, masking, nor math is needed - just like OP did.

```
unsigned long some_unsigned_long_object = some_int_value;
```

The trick is when `some_int_value < 0`.  The value saved will be `some_int_value + ULONG_MAX + 1`.  [@AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294434/how-to-assign-an-int-to-unsigned-long-using-c/40294530#comment67847359_40294434) Now is this OK for OP's code?  Perhaps not.

A safer conversion would test for negativeness first.

```
int session_total = npu_session_total();
if (session_total < 0) {
  Handle_Negative_Case(session_total);
}
else {
  unsigned long accelerated_count = npu_session_total();
  ...
}
```

[@OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294434/how-to-assign-an-int-to-unsigned-long-using-c/40294530#comment67847452_40294434) comments that the `int` value *should* never be negative.  Defensive coding would still detect negative values and handle that.  Maybe a simple error message and exit.

Comment: Casting (conversion) is implicit because the compiler doesn't ask you if you are sure about that implicit conversion and assumes that you know what are you doing. So this means, that trying to compile this kind of code, you have to turn Off the compiler FLAGS, if not, [an explicit casting](http://ideone.com/gfpoMP) is needed:  =>> `unsigned long accelerated_count = (unsigned long)npu_session_total();`. Any way this is a good Answer.

Comment: I think you are right. For me, I thought the session count is always positive, but after printing it out, I did see a bunch of negative values. I think I need to handle those negative cases. Can I just do "(unsigned long)npu_session_total()"?

Comment: @d22shen `(unsigned long)npu_session_total()` will simply change the value from negative to some (large) `unsigned long` value.  The point is that code may need to perform different functionality.  Might as well test `session_total < 0` and split on that.